# facebook graph api how to differenciate between original post and shared post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to find out if a post is a shared post or an original post. How can I do that if I have the postId.

Eg: this post https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10154014383452823&id=74281347822

This is a shared post when we look at the facebook link above. Can I get this information from the graph-api:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10154014383452823&version=v2.2

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting a "status" and not a "post" - that doesn't have what you need - but finding the post will.

Once you find the post_id, use the `post` graph point and look at `parent_id`.

Since API 2.4 "statuses" are now "posts" and API 2.2 is going bye-bye March 25th 2017 so you'll need to start thinking in terms of "post" and not status anyway.

Comment: How to get the post_id from the this url https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10154014383452823&id=74281347822? All I have is just this url, if the story_fbid is statusid, how can I get the post id??

Comment: From one of the feeds - Facebook specifically prevent you getting the ids from the website or urls. See the note in this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/status but it applies both ways...

Comment: _"All I have is just this url"_ - your app should not work with arbitrary identifiers fed into it from the outside. If you read data in an allowed way (f.e. a user's feed), then you would have the necessary id value already.